# How to enable exceptions in mongoid/moped/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, moped

My setup fails silently when I `order_by` an unknown attribute. Is there a way to change this behavior, to fail fast with an error/exception?

It makes debugging code extremely difficult.